# Spring Boot Java Client not able to connect to Zeebe Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, zeebe

I ran the zeebe in local using operate from zeebe-docker-compose
https://github.com/zeebe-io/zeebe-docker-compose/blob/master/operate/docker-compose.yml

Using the example from read me : Tried to connect to the zeebe using this configuration from spring-zeebe-starter:

version: 1.0.0-rc1

```
zeebe.client.broker.gatewayAddress=127.0.0.1:26500
zeebe.client.security.plaintext=true
```

But it refuses the connection :

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'zeebeClientLifecycle'; nested exception is io.camunda.zeebe.client.api.command.ClientStatusException: io exception
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:63) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at com.rupeek.orchestrator.TMSApplication.main(TMSApplication.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: io.camunda.zeebe.client.api.command.ClientStatusException: io exception
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.ZeebeClientFutureImpl.transformExecutionException(ZeebeClientFutureImpl.java:93) ~[zeebe-client-java-1.0.0-rc1.jar:1.0.0-rc1]
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.ZeebeClientFutureImpl.join(ZeebeClientFutureImpl.java:50) ~[zeebe-client-java-1.0.0-rc1.jar:1.0.0-rc1]
    at io.zeebe.spring.client.config.processor.DeploymentPostProcessor.lambda$apply$3(DeploymentPostProcessor.java:49) ~[spring-zeebe-1.0.0-rc1.jar:1.0.0-rc1]
    at io.zeebe.spring.client.ZeebeClientLifecycle.lambda$start$0(ZeebeClientLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-zeebe-1.0.0-rc1.jar:1.0.0-rc1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at io.zeebe.spring.client.ZeebeClientLifecycle.start(ZeebeClientLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-zeebe-1.0.0-rc1.jar:1.0.0-rc1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2063) ~[na:na]
    at io.camunda.zeebe.client.impl.ZeebeClientFutureImpl.join(ZeebeClientFutureImpl.java:48) ~[zeebe-client-java-1.0.0-rc1.jar:1.0.0-rc1]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535) ~[grpc-api-1.37.0.jar:1.37.0]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:478) ~[grpc-stub-1.37.0.jar:1.37.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:463) ~[grpc-core-1.37.0.jar:1.37.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:427) ~[grpc-core-1.37.0.jar:1.37.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:460) ~[grpc-core-1.37.0.jar:1.37.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:553) ~[grpc-core-1.37.0.jar:1.37.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:68) ~[grpc-core-1.37.0.jar:1.37.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:739) ~[grpc-core-1.37.0.jar:1.37.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:718) ~[grpc-core-1.37.0.jar:1.37.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.37.0.jar:1.37.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[grpc-core-1.37.0.jar:1.37.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: /0.0.0.0:26500
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newConnectException0(Errors.java:155) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.handleConnectErrno(Errors.java:128) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:278) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:710) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.63.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:687) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.63.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:567) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.63.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:470) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.63.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.63.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:4.1.63.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:an]
```

Application.java File :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZeebeClient
@RestController
@ZeebeDeployment(classPathResources = {"sample.bpmn"})
public class SampleApplication {

    @Autowired
    private ZeebeClientLifecycle client;

///// Some methods 


}
```

Comment: Why do you use 1.0.0-rc1 if there is already 1.0.0 out?

Comment: What OS are you on? The docker network needs to map to 127.0.0.1. Windows may have an issue with this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? I am struggling with the same error

Answer (score 0):

The exception looks like it is unable to connect to your local zeebe container. I would recommend seeing if your zeebe container is actually healthy by taking the following steps if you haven't already:

1. Confirm your zeebe container is running
2. Look at your zeebe logs and check for errors. Super easy to do with [docker desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/)
3. If you see that your zeebe container is running and there are no error logs, try connecting with zbctl command: `zbctl --insecure --address localhost:26500 status`

If #3 returns a healthy status than you know it is a configuration with the spring-boot app.

If #3 shows you can't connect than there is a problem with the zeebe container or potentially your port binding or something else which needs to be fixed first before even trying to connect via spring boot client.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these:

1. **Your application is inside of a docker-container**
   In that case, you have to use a new docker-compose.yml where both applications are defined.
2. **Your docker is running somewhere else**
   When you have docker on a different place (like in case of Windows with WSL2), then you have to setup a link between your host and the virtual machine. See [WSL2 (docker) ports are not openend on host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69838995/wsl2-docker-ports-are-not-openend-on-host)
3. **Zeebe not running**
   Did you start the docker-compose? See [Ryans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78232606/6537157) for more hints