# WSL2 (docker) ports are not openend on host

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run an image through docker in WSL2, the ports are not published on the host machine. Why is this? What can I do to make this work?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The reason is that WSL2 runs a VM with your OS of choice on it. If you want to access WSL2 services through ports on the Windows machine, you need to run a proxy on the Windows end that forwards traffic to the WSL2 VM. You can use `netsh` although it's a bit of a mess. https://dev.to/vishnumohanrk/wsl-port-forwarding-2e22. Downloading a Windows version of `ncat` might give you commands that are easier to remember.

Comment: I just restarted WSL with `wsl --shutdown` and tried the same thing again and now it works. You make it sound like it should never work like this?

Comment: I would think that it wouldn't. When you run the docker command from WSL, the WSL VM is the host. I just checked and the Windows side and the WSL VM have different IP addresses, so I'm a bit surprised that the WSL ports are exposed on the WIndows end automatically. But great if it works like you want out of the box.

Comment: This appears to have been the issue for me https://superuser.com/a/1671709/28261

Comment: This post identified a windows-update bug and seems to have fixed it for me https://superuser.com/a/1671709/28261 Reboot afterwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So while I still don't know *why* this happens (sometimes) it appears a restart fixes it (temporarily?):

*(on windows cmd)*

```
> wsl --shutdown
```

Re-running the same commands as above yields mapped ports also visible ob the windows host machine:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -ano | findstr 55580
  TCP    127.0.0.1:55580        0.0.0.0:0              ABHÖREN         12392
  TCP    [::1]:55580            [::]:0                 ABHÖREN         12392
```

The `12392` PID is `wslhost.exe`

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to make port forward, as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4983#issuecomment-1560668422).

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=<port d'écoute sur la machine Windows> listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=<port de destination sur la machine Linux> connectaddress=<adresse IP machine Linux>

New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2' -Direction Outbound -LocalPort "<port d'écoute sur la machine Windows>" -Action Allow -Protocol TCP

New-NetFireWallRule -DisplayName 'WSL 2' -Direction Inbound -LocalPort "<port d'écoute sur la machine Windows>" -Action Allow -Protocol TCP
```

I'm not sure it is the right way but it works.

Hope it will help :)